# Fade in after background fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm putting together this website: www.mccraymusic.com/newsite and I am trying to make it so that the navigation bar (which I know is not styled) fades in after the background fades in. Instead it seems to want to fade out.

I thought I have all the code in place and javascript correct. I actually want it so that the navigation bar and content I add to the site will fade in, after the initial background fade in occurs.

Do you I need to move some stuff around in my html? or how can I achieve this? I don't think I'm far from getting what I want

Answer (score 3):

To start an animation after another, you can use the callback of `.fadeIn()` (or any effect function). Something like:

```
$( "#div1" ).fadeIn(function(){ $( "#div2" ).fadeIn(); });
```

Or (easier to read):

```
$( "#div1" ).fadeIn(function(){
    $( "#div2" ).fadeIn();
});
```

`div1` will fade in, and when it finishes, `div2` will start to fade in.

Take a look in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 0):

I used this to fade stuff in with jQuery... pros will tell you this is a terrible practice... because you have the div initially set to display: none...  and if javascript is off - then it will never fade in...  but this works.  and if it's just for a band or artist - chances are - no one is going to be looking at this site on IE 6 etc... but look in to no.js or whatever and have a back up plan.

```
 <!--fade in div-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#div-name").css("display", "none");
                $("#div-name").fadeIn(15000);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try callback function of jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("body.bg").fadeIn(200,function(){
$('.second').fadeIn()
});
});
</script>
```